# Is there any timeout for function cx_Oracle.connect(usr,pwd,host:port/service)?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm using cx_Oracle module to connect to Oracle DB. Is there any timeout for `cx_Oracle.connect(usr,pwd,host:port/service)`? If DB is down for some reason or if host is not reachable, then code is getting hanged at `connect()`, `connect()` method is taking very long time to return. Is there any way to get timeout issue ? any way to change cx_Oracle default timeout ?

```
import cx_Oracle
try:
    conn=cx_Oracle.connect('usr/pwd@host:port/service')
    print "Success"
    conn.close()
except Exception,e:
    print "Error:"
    print str(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Timeouts are handled by the Oracle Net layer and OS network.  Look at configuring your sqlnet.ora file.  To quote myself from the node-oracledb doc (all these drivers use Oracle Net):

> For Oracle Net configuration, set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN
>   to your application configuration directory and create the file
>   $TNS_ADMIN/sqlnet.ora. In this file you can configure settings like
>   SQLNET.OUTBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT and
>   SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT. You may also want to use a tnsnames.ora file to
>   configure the database service setting 'ENABLE=BROKEN'.
>
> Other Oracle Net options may also be useful for high availability and
>   performance tuning.

Update: for execution (not connection time) timeouts, cx_Oracle 7.0 introduced a [Connection.callTimeout](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.callTimeout) parameter that can be used in place of some of the Oracle Net settings. It requires you to have Oracle client libraries 18c, or greater.